# Google Sheet Scripts: How to compare only one column to remove duplicates

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

There are 4 dupes in this example sheet(rows 2-5): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CMR9TjtxIGF7QDFBEMBSbAcd71neSjteINvmeuvZ3lo/edit#gid=0

I'd like to compare only only `column B`(`Link`) for removal, but this script compares all cells in a row

```
function removeDuplicates() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Combined');
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const numRows = data.length;
  const newData = [];
  const seen = {};

  for (var i = 0, row, key; i < numRows && (row = data[i]); i++) {
    key = JSON.stringify(row);
    if (key in seen) {
      continue;
    }
    seen[key] = true;
    newData.push(row);
  }

  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);

}
```

How can I make it to just compare `column B` to delete the dupes without losing information when writing back to the sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to remove the rows that the values of column "B" are duplicated.
- You want to clear all contents of the sheet and overwrite the new values without the duplicated values.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Pattern 1:

When your script is modified, how about this modification?

From:

```
for (var i = 0, row, key; i < numRows && (row = data[i]); i++) {
  key = JSON.stringify(row);
  if (key in seen) {
    continue;
  }
  seen[key] = true;
  newData.push(row);
}
```

To:

```
for (var i = 0, row, key; i < numRows && (row = data[i][1]); i++) { // Modified
  if (row in seen) { // Modified
    continue;
  }
  seen[row] = true; // Modified
  newData.push(data[i]); // Modified
}
```

#### Pattern 2:

As other pattern, how about this modified script?

```
function removeDuplicates_modified() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Combined');
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var temp = {}; // Added
  var newData = data.reduce(function(ar, e) { // Added
    if (!temp[e[1]]) {
      ar.push(e);
      temp[e[1]] = e[1];
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);

  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

#### Note:

- In your sample Spreadsheet, the values of column "D" and "B" are not duplicated, while the values of column "B" are duplicated. If you want to process about this, please tell me.

#### Reference:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

### Added:

#### Pattern 3:

When your script is modified, I noticed more simple modification. Please check the following modification.

From:

```
key = JSON.stringify(row);
```

To:

```
key = row[1];
```

#### Pattern 4:

When `filter` is used, how about this modification?

```
function removeDuplicates_modified() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Combined');
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var temp = {}; // Added
  var newData = data.filter(function(e) { // Added
    if (!temp[e[1]]) {
      temp[e[1]] = e[1];
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });

  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Appreciate the introduction on `reduce()`! You understood the requirements perfectly.

Comment: @sojim2 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: @sojim2 I added 2 patterns.

Comment: `filter()` looks much much simpler to follow, I prefer using that one!