# Google Sheet Scripts: How to compare 2 columns to remove duplicates

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

There are 3 duplicate articles from the same domain in `Sheet1`: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pExqHJQubnSPDKczkF9HMA2QN1cxTYmzyewQdugDRYs/edit#gid=0

**Goal:** I'd like to remove articles that have the same title AND domain.

Sheet `DesiredResult` has the desired result.

I'd like to modify this filter script to compare article title(`column a`) & domain(`column C`), if they are the same, then remove:

```
function removeDuplicates() {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

    var temp = {}; // Added
    var newData = data.filter(function(e) { // Added
        if (!temp[e[1]]) {
            temp[e[1]] = e[1];
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });

    sheet.clearContents();
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Right now it just looks at the link if they're the same. It's not using an `if` statement so I'm not sure how to add a comparison for 2 columns. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

**Update:** I've tried looking at `!temp[e[1]]` to see if there are values to compare in an `if` statement but it shows as `undefined` so I'm stuck where to add the second column comparison in this section.

**Reference:** Previous question, asked to compare 1 column - [Google Sheet Scripts: How to compare only one column to remove duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57032493/google-sheet-scripts-how-to-compare-only-one-column-to-remove-duplicates)

Comment: Not sure why this is too broad, can the person who voted that explain so I can improve in the future?

Comment: There isn't any recognizable attempt made to modify the code to achieve your goal. You just copy pated previously provided code.

Comment: Fair, added an update section where I got stuck when I looked at `temp[e[1]]`

Comment: You might want to **practice** [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp) and the next 4 chapters there(especially Array#filter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to remove the duplicated rows by comparing the column "A" and "C".

  - In your shared spreadsheet, you want to modify from `Sheet1` to `DesiredResult`.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? In this modification, the method of `removeDuplicates()` is used. This was added at July 26, 2019. So [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57032493/7108653) had been posted at July 15, 2019, unfortunately, at that time, this method had not been added yet. Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modified script:

```
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Combined');
sheet.getDataRange().removeDuplicates([1, 3]);
```

#### Note:

- When you test above modified script to the shared Spreadsheet, please modify the sheet name from `Combined` to `Sheet1`.

#### Reference:

- [removeDuplicates(columnsToCompare)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#removeduplicatescolumnstocompare)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

### Added:

If you want to modify your script, how about the following modification? Also please think of this just one of several answers.

#### From:

```
if (!temp[e[1]]) {
    temp[e[1]] = e[1];
```

#### To:

```
if (!temp[e[0] + e[2]]) {
    temp[e[0] + e[2]] = e[1];
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, I wanted to regex match `e[1]` so the custom script you've provided works perfectly for my use case. Really great to know there's a built in function, but I don't think I can add `regex match` to it. This is what I did: `temp[e[0] + e[1].match(/\w+\.(com|org)/g)] = e[1];` Thank you!!

Comment: @sojim2 Thank you for replying and additional information. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var data=sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = data.filter(function(r) {
    return !(r[0]==r[2])//comparing column A with Column C
  }); 
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Test it on this Data:

```
1,a,a
2,b,a
3,c,a
4,a,a
5,b,a
6,c,6
7,a,7
8,b,8
9,c,9
```

[Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Hmm, I tried the code on the example sheet but it's not working: https://i.imgur.com/wIr8jdA.gif

Comment: Please share some data that includes columns A and C as described in your question `I'd like to modify this filter script to compare article title(column a) & domain(column C), if they are the same, then remove:`

Comment: This works on my data.  Note: I don't want an image of the data.